# Rails Execute Cron Job or Rake task for specific time period

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cron, scheduled-tasks, rake-task

I want to execute some task for a specific time period. Lets say I want to execute cronjob or some rake task between 6am to 9am for every half an hour. So script will get execute 6, 6:30, 7, 7:30... and last at 9.

Can you please give me some suggestion that how I can do this with Rails.

Don't tell me that schedule individual task for 6, 6:30, 7.. time period.

**ANS**
Simplest way I have found is to use whenever gem and adding cronjob time as below.

```
every '*/30 6-9 * * *' do
  runner "Model.method"
end
```

Answer (score 1):

One of the easiest ways to do this is via the Ruby gem called `whenever`. It provides you a really nice DSL (domain-specific language) you can use in order to do exactly what you want. I've used it before for server app deployments, and it's worked like a charm!

Here is a link to the gem repository on Github:
**https://github.com/javan/whenever**

Here is also a great RailsCast you can watch on how to set it up in Rails:
**http://railscasts.com/episodes/164-cron-in-ruby**

---

You should be able to do something like this:

```
every :day, :at => (6..8).to_a.map { |x| ["#{x}:00","#{x}:30", "#{x+1}:00"] }.flatten do
  # Run rake task.
end

# => ["6:00", "6:30", "7:00", "7:00", "7:30", "8:00", "8:00", "8:30", "9:00"]
```

You can adjust the initial range and the inner block to cover any range you want. `whenever` conveniently handles military time format (24hr clock), which makes this great to use.

Hope that helps!

Comment: I will work on this tomorrow and let you know the status. Anyways thanks for the reply. I hope that this solution will help.

Comment: I have used whenever gem added cronjob delegation. Check my edited question. Thanks.

Comment: Awesome that you can use the actual cron task notation in via the whenever gem. Glad I could help!

Answer (score 1):

I like to use delayed_job for scheduled tasks - https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job

When you enque a job you can specify the run_at attribute

Comment: This is not the delayed job.

Comment: "execute cronjob or some rake task" - if you are executing ruby code, what I am saying is you can put that code into a Delayed Job object (move it out of rake task) and use the delayed job scheduling via `run_at` rails is much better at handling timezones and day light savings time than cron

Comment: This will be too expensive no? And also I don't want to take care of timezones of day light savings. Thanks Anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post but it just came up for me so I thought I'd chime in. I use the whenever gem for my cron jobs and have one that needs to execute every minute but only during US stock trading hours. In my schedule.rb I have:

```
every '*/1 09-17 * * *' do 
 rake "rake_namespace:rake_task"
end
```